# Wrapping text in Sidewaystables

Tags: tables, rotating, wrap

I'm trying to make a rotated table using the `sidewaystable` package, and I cannot get the text to wrap. It compiles, but it I haven't been able to wrap the text within the columns or define the width of the columns.

The code is rather messy but here is an extract:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]  
  \centering  
  \caption{bla bla bla}  
   \begin{threeparttable}[b]  
    \begin{tabular}{rrr}  
    \toprule  
          Awesome intro\\  
    \midrule  
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{bla bla} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{more bla} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{final bla} \\  
\bottomrule  
    \end{tabular}%  
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize  
        \item Source: bla bla  
         \end{tablenotes}  
    \end{threeparttable}  
  \label{tab:xx}%  
\end{sidewaystable}%
```

Edit:

- It is also going on a seperate page in the appendix, if that makes a difference..
- I am using the `threeparttable` to be add "footnotes" to the tables.

Comment: Instead of `\begin{tabular}{rrr}` try `\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{8cm}p{4cm}}` or whatever width you need.

Comment: Tried that but there is no difference.
I've tried with different sizes too

Comment: Get rid of all those `\multicolumn{1}{l}{text}` which are overriding the `p{<length>}` column type: `\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}  
    \toprule  
          a  \    \midrule  
    bla bla & more bla & final bla \\  
\bottomrule  
    \end{tabular}`

Comment: Welcome to the site, Anders. Could you extend your "snippet" into a compilable `.tex` file, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`? It is easier to reproduce the issue you're having if I can just paste your code into my editor and hit "compile" `:-)`.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo!
Removing all the \multicolumns worked!
I know that they are superfluous in some cases, but I am using an excel to latex table exporter which does it by default. 
Which is proving to be less of a time saver than I thought!

Without using multicolumns, how will i be able to merge two columns?

Answer (score 1):

Use `p{...}` type columns and avoid the `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` which override the initial column type; you can still use `\multicolumn` with a `p{...}` column type to merge several columns. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]  
  \centering  
  \caption{bla bla bla}  
   \begin{threeparttable}[b]  
    \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}  
    \toprule  
          Awesome intro\\  
    \midrule  
    Some test text spanning several lines & Some test text spanning several lines  & Some test text spanning several lines  \\ 
   \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering}p{8cm}}{Some test text spanning several lines in a multicolumn for two columns} & Some test text spanning several lines \\
\bottomrule  
    \end{tabular}%  
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize  
        \item Source: bla bla  
         \end{tablenotes}  
    \end{threeparttable}  
  \label{tab:xx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]